# Creating a partial view for a dropdownlist

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My view model

```
public class MyTest
{
   public string CountryId {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Countries {get; set;}
}
```

My view

```
@Model MyTest

@{
  ViewBag._SelectList = MyTest.Countries;

  //I want to call the partial view by
  Html.Partial("_Dropdownlist"); //and specify the property x => x.CountryId
}
```

I am creating a partial view that I can use for all dropdownlists
_Dropdownlist.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(<I need to use the property here>, ViewBag._SelectList)
```

How do I pass the lambda expression `x => x.CountryId` to the partial view so that I can reuse the DropDownList.cshtml across multiple views.

PS: I don't want to use `Html.DropDownList`

Thanks

Comment: @Dude...are you saying you want CountryId to be the property of the Model that the DropDownListFor helper is attached to?  Or are you saying you want that paramater to be generic?

Comment: I want that parameter to be generic

Comment: @Dude...well, you could use a generic ViewBag item and set it in the controller action with the appropriate Property from each Model.  Similar to your ViewBag._SelectList.

Comment: @Dude....did my suggestionhelp...or did you find a solution?

Comment: I couldn't get too far with it. Not sure how to cast the `ViewBag` item? It's expecting a `Expression<Func<Model, int>>` type